# Rails asset pipeline doesn't load javascript dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've been following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I am having trouble loading JavaScript dependencies as part of the 8th chapter: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login

The CSS dependencies load fine (I'm using bootstrap), and upon inspecting the page in the browser there are multiple `<link rel="stylesheet...>` tags in the head. However, there is only one script tag, which loads the compiled `application.js` file.

The interesting thing is, even if I make mistakes in the js manifest file, such as requiring a file that does not exist, I do not get any errors when rendering my pages in a browser.

I've tried reproducing this in a fresh app, but I was unable to. Simply requiring the needed gems in the Gemfile, `bundle install` and visiting any page than the default rails one, will include all dependencies listed in the application.js manifest file as separate `<script src=..>` tags in the `<head>`.

I'm loading the assets as part of the `layouts/application.html.erb` file, using the helpers:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                    'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

`application.js` manifest file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My RoR and Ruby versions are 5.1 and 2.3.2 respectively.
The js manifest file is `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: Yeah the bootstrap gem was there, however, it would not load any dependency at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the relevant parts of my main app into a fresh rails app that did load the JS dependencies. I expect this to have been a configuration problem on my side.

More specifically, I moved the Gemfile, db/, config/routes.rb and everything from app/ (except config/) into a fresh rails app. Once everything worked I overwrote my main application's app/ directory with the one from the fresh app.